# Reading one chunk at a time in Django

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn, chunked-encoding

Our setup is Nginx, Gunicorn and Django.
I'm trying to add functionality that proxies Chunked Transfer Encoding as an HTTP post request http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding
But even though we were able to read the chunked data (after installing nginx_extras), it arrives as a single packet (in request.raw_post_data).

How can I read one chunk at a time?

I'm not sure which of Nginx, Gunicorn or Django buffers the entire post message...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly I just found out that NginX buffers the entire message.
Or so says Yichun Zhang who wrote the Nginx chunking module.